# Keyerror: 'pose' when training tflite file from pascal voc

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using the tflite_model_maker package to train an object_detector tflite model. When I try to import data from pascal voc, I get KeyError: 'pose' error. What am I doing wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2main.py", line 7, in <module>
    dataloader = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc('data/images', 'data/annotations', label_map=label_map)
  File "/home/luke/moneyDetector/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/data_util/object_detector_dataloader.py", line 217, in from_pascal_voc
    cache_writer.write_files(
  File "/home/luke/moneyDetector/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/data_util/object_detector_dataloader_util.py", line 252, in write_files
    tf_example = create_pascal_tfrecord.dict_to_tf_example(
  File "/home/luke/moneyDetector/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/third_party/efficientdet/dataset/create_pascal_tfrecord.py", line 176, in dict_to_tf_example
    poses.append(obj['pose'].encode('utf8'))
KeyError: 'pose'
```

Edit: For further context, I believe the annotations were created by exporting from [cvat](https://github.com/opencv/cvat)

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because your annotation file don't have attribute 'pose'.
I had the same issue when I was using CVAT as an annotation tool and realized that the 'pose' and 'truncated' was missing.
So I imported my annotated data to another annotation tool (LabelImg) then export to pascal voc again. I don't think this is the best way, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I exported the data from CVAT tool and I've managed to fix it with this script:

```py
import xmltodict
from dict2xml import dict2xml
import glob


def postprocessor(path, key, value):
    if key == 'object':
        if 'pose' not in value:
            value['pose'] = 'Unspecified'
        value['bndbox']['xmax'] = int(float(value['bndbox']['xmax']))
        value['bndbox']['xmin'] = int(float(value['bndbox']['xmin']))
        value['bndbox']['ymax'] = int(float(value['bndbox']['ymax']))
        value['bndbox']['ymin'] = int(float(value['bndbox']['ymin']))
    if not value:
        return key, []
    return key, value


xml_files = glob.glob(
    f"{annotations_in}/*.xml",
    recursive=True)

for xml_file in xml_files:
    # Open the file and read the contents
    with open(xml_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        src_xml = file.read()

    my_dict = xmltodict.parse(src_xml, postprocessor=postprocessor)
    dist_xml = dict2xml(my_dict)

    with open(xml_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(dist_xml)
```